# error in trigger function to determine PK names automatically and auto increments the last PK group by pervious PKs

Tags: postgresql

I just create a trigger function to add last primary keys(PK) automatically groups to PKs added prior. Since this function will be attached to some tables with different PK.

It was successfully when creating, but It was Error when I insert new record(s)

Here's the code

```
FUNCTION public.detail_seq_ins() (plpgsql)

declare ex text;
begin
    select 'select coalesce($1."'||key_||'",coalesce(max(a."'||key_||'"),0)+1) into strict $1."'||key_||'" from ' || TG_TABLE_NAME ||  ' a where '||cols
    into ex
    from 
        (
          SELECT (array_agg(column_name))[count(*)] as key_, array_to_string((array_agg('a."'||column_name||'"=$1."'||column_name||'"'))[1:count(*)-1],' and ') as cols
          FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
          WHERE table_name=TG_TABLE_NAME and constraint_name like '%\_pkey'
        ) a;
    
    execute ex using NEW;  
    return NEW;
end;
```

and unfortunately it returning Error,after executing insert :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: ...($1."did",coalesce(max(a."did"),0)+1) into strict $1."did" f...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  select coalesce($1."did",coalesce(max(a."did"),0)+1) into strict $1."did" from vendor_gateway_d_p a where a."id"=$1."id"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function detail_seq_ins() line 13 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

My goals is to determine PK names automatically and auto increments the last PK group by pervious PKs

Here's the Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.vendor_gateway_d_p
(
    id smallint NOT NULL,
    did smallint NOT NULL,
    protocol character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    cptr bigint DEFAULT 0,
    "gateId" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "gatePwd" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    status smallint DEFAULT 0,
    host character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    channel text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "UID" character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "PWDorPIN" character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "queryBal" character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "responseBal" character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "queryDep" character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "reponseDep" character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "queryTrx" character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "responseTrx" character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    enabled boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    usecode boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT vendor_gateway_d_p_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, did),
    CONSTRAINT vendor_gateway_d_p_d_p_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES public.vendor_m_p (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT vendor_gateway_d_p_protocol_check CHECK (eg_check_protocol(protocol))
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Here's the Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER vendor_gateway_d_p_detail_seq_ins_trig1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON public.vendor_gateway_d_p
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.detail_seq_ins();
```

Here's the command I used to insert the table

```
delete from  public.vendor_gateway_d_p;
insert into public.vendor_gateway_d_p (id,did,protocol,host,channel,"queryTrx","UID","PWDorPIN","gateId","gatePwd")
values (1,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'),
       (1,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'),
       (1,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'),
       (43,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'),
       (43,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'),
       (21,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'),
       (21,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'),
       (21,NULL,'JB','*','*','*','*','*','*','*')
```

Desired Result,

```
|id|did|...
| 1|  1|...
| 1|  2|...
| 1|  3|...
|43|  1|...
|43|  2|...
|21|  1|...
|21|  2|...
|21|  3|...
```

May get some light to know about my mistakes
Thanks a lot

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and the trigger (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito), a statement that should fire the trigger and the desired result with that sample data after the trigger has fired in tabular text format.

Comment: OK I have edited

Comment: Can you please condense that? I.e. respect the aspect of minimality in [example]? And you didn't include the desired results as well.

Comment: Well. Hope it done

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it solved since  I use extension hstore.

I modify the code to be like this.

```
declare 
    ex text;
    k text;
    _id integer;
begin
    select 'select coalesce($1."'||key_||'",coalesce(max(a."'||key_||'"),0)+1) aa from ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA||'.'||TG_TABLE_NAME ||  ' a where '||cols, key_
    into ex,k
    from 
        (
          SELECT (array_agg(column_name))[count(*)] as key_, array_to_string((array_agg('a."'||column_name||'"=$1."'||column_name||'"'))[1:count(*)-1],' and ') as cols
          FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
          WHERE table_schema=TG_TABLE_SCHEMA and table_name=TG_TABLE_NAME and constraint_name like '%\_pkey'
        ) a;
    
    execute ex into _id using NEW;  
    NEW := NEW #= ('"'||k||'"=>'||_id)::hstore;
    return NEW;
end;
```